# Solving a pip issue using a range vs removing package range altogether

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm getting a conflict with a pip install and I get this message:

```
To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

So if I have, let's say:

```
pandas==1.1.2
```

I could put:

```
pandas>=1.1.0,<1.1.4
```

But would using:

```
pandas
```

simply look through all possibilities and fix it itself?

I'm not sure If I'm being clear, but basically, if I don't care about version number, can I just use no versions as a better solution, because it would implicitly go through the all the ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this might fix your issue as @linger1109 suggested, it is highly recommended to specify a version number in your dependency manifest (e.g. `requirements.txt`.

There is no guarantee that future versions of pandas are fully backwards compatible, meaning the next time you install your dependencies, pip might opt for a newer version of pandas, potentially breaking your code.

I'd suggest finding versions of dependencies that are compatible with each other and declaring them in your dependencies manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, running the command
`pip install pandas` will find the most recent version that can be used.

Comment: But what if I want it to go through every version until it can successfully install?